# Java: JSONParseException

Tags: java, json

All I'm trying to do is to parse very simple json line, even its valid i dont know why its throwing an error

the line is

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{publish_status:'active',activation_date:{$lt:new Date()},expiration_date:{$gt:new Date()}}
                                               ^
```

what is wrong with the `new Date()` as a value?

Comment: Yep, that isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @poitroae I'm trying to get the records that has activation date less than now and expiration date grater than now ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid JSON at all. JSON syntax is defined on [json.org](http://www.json.org/), and it's always a string key with a value that's one of a string, number, boolean, null, array, or object. You're writing a Mongo query from Java. You should reformulate your question and retag appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the new date() in mongo DB 2.2.3 directly and it worked .. it created a value of ISODate.

You may try using this:

```
{publish_status:'active',activation_date:new Date(),expiration_date:new Date()}
```

Comment: I need the $lt & $gt operators,

Comment: Date date = new Date();
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
 query.put("expiration_date",   BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gt",date).get());
 query.put("activation_date", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$lt",date).get());
 DBObject document = collection.findOne(query);

Comment: Try out the above code .. i used Java 1.7 and mongo dB 2.2.3 and mongo driver as 2.10.1